# Pythonic approach to zipping items in a list

Tags: python

Say I want to iterate through a list. Each time I iterate I want to compute something using both the current and next terms. I could do something like

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    try:
        compute(mylist[i], mylist[i+1])
    except IndexError:
        compute(mylist[i])
```

I could also do

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for num in mylist:
    try:
        compute(num, mylist[mylist.index(num)+1])
    except IndexError:
        compute(num)
```

Neither of these seems particularly good. Is there a more pythonic approach to doing this?

Comment: You can try using the `pairwise` recipe from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

Comment: @Wessie: That's exactly what he should do... You should make that into an answer.

Comment: Why do you call `compute` with only one argument on the last iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do that (although I would probably prefer first one, unless your conditions are different):

1. Use `itertools.izip()` - it will be efficient and Pythonic:

   ```
   for item1, item2 in itertools.izip(my_list, my_list[1:]):
       # do something...
   ```
2. Use `enumerate()`:

   ```
   for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
       # do something...
   ```
3. Store previous row in a variable (the example assumes there is no `None` in your list):

   ```
   previous = None
   for item in my_list:
       if previous is None:
           previous = item
           continue
       # do something...
   ```

Comment: +1 Option 1 is probably the best imho.

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in function `enumerate`:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i, num in enumerate(mylist):
    try:
        compute(num, mylist[i+1])
    except IndexError:
        compute(num)
```

But choosing between your two implementations is rather easy - second is not only far slower (`O(n^2)`), but also has weird semantics for repeating elements.

Answer (score 0):

A functional style that doesn't use itertools might look something like:

```
for t in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]):
    compute(*t)
```

If performance is tantamount you can prevent the creation of the intermeida list during zip by using [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

To cover the special case as shown in the question, use:

```
for t in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]) + [(mylist[-1],)]
    compute(*t)
```

Comment: Why is this inefficient?

Comment: It isn't actually that bad, but zip creates an intermediate list that  is unnecessary. Using [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

To cover your special case at the end, you need:

```
for t in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]) + [(mylist[-1],)]
    compute(*t)
```